# Two different expressions for the Schwarzschild Radius?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes

This might sound as quite an obvious question at first, but in most places the expression I've seen for this radius is: $$\frac{2GM}{c^2}$$
but in other places, I've seen the expression as:$$\approx \frac{GM}{c^2}$$
The second case always had the $\approx$ sign. How can such an approximation be accurate? ( I don't think it is) . What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: The one *with* the factor 2 is correct. The obvious [wikipedia search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) would have shown you this. I'm voting to close based on insufficient research effort. Note that OP has since edited the question; it still isn't a good one, in my opinion.

Comment: I wanted to know about the second formula I've mentioned, but I am aware of the formula being the one with the 2.

Comment: Your question is still quite trivial, since it is quite typical to ignore constants of order 1, so there's really nothing of interest here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact value is the first formula you have provided. The second one expresses the order of magnitude of the Schwarzschild radius, as any factor of 2 is practically irrelevant to it.